# How do I add a username to multiple AD groups from a csv file chosen through a file browser popup

Tags: powershell, active-directory-group

I am working on the following script to prompt for a user name to add to a list of AD groups that are saved in a .csv file that is picked from the file browser.

```
# Store credentials for use in this script for multiple instances.
$Credential = Get-Credential

# Prompt for User to add to groups.
$user = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter username to add to AD Groups."

Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory) {
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null

    $OpenFileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileBrowser.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $OpenFileBrowser.filter = "CSV (*.csv)| *.csv"
    $OpenFileBrowser.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    $OpenFileBrowser.filename
}

#Gets the csv file and uses its data.
$file = Get-FileName #Function created to select a single csv file.
$Groups = Get-Content $file

"Adding Users to the following group: $Group"
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Groups -members $user -Credential $Credential
```

I get an error when it comes to the Identity what am I doing wrong?

> ```
> Adding Users to the following group: Groups ADSelfService Box_Users
> Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup' required by parameter 'Identity'. Specified method is not supported.
> At P:\PowerShell Scripts\Add-UserADGroup.ps1:24 char:29
> + Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Groups -members $user -Credential $Crede ...
> +                             ~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-ADGroupMember], ParameterBindingException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember
> ```

Comment: Please show us the csv file you are loading. You cannot use an array of textlines (which you get from `Get-Content $file`) as Identity parameter for function `Add-ADGroupMember`. Read all about that function here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/add-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps. As for reading a CSV file, use `Import-Csv`. This parses the CSV and returns an array of objects with the properties in the csv file. Iterate through the rows and pick he appropriate properties to use. (one at a time)

Comment: I suspect it might be because you are missing a `foreach` loop to add them. You might be trying to add the entire Array

Comment: You also don't pass an `$initialDirectory` to the function.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `$Groups` is not a string with the group name.
If you do `$Groups.ToString()` and assuming that the data is just a single group or something else the command can read it should work.

What seems to happen is that the command tries to match the object type with an input object since it doesn't get the normal string it expects it seems like.

Since your object is not an AD group piped from the AD it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your csv file contains valid Active Directory group names line by line without any headers?

If yes, try to alter your code like that (untested):

```
Import-Csv -Path $file -Header "GroupName " | foreach {

    "Adding Users to the following group: $Group"
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.GroupName -members $user -Credential $Credential
}
```